# Protobuf-net serialization of object (generic) throws error No serializer defined for type: System.Object

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

How to serialize a **generic(T) object** which can hold any type of data (*int / string / DateTime*) using Protobuf-net. Following is my code

```csharp
[ProtoContract]
public class E1DataRow
{
  [ProtoMember(1)]
  public List<NameValue> NameValues { get; set; }

  public E1DataRow()
  {
    NameValues = new List<NameValue>();
  }

  public void AddNameValue(string name, object obj, Type type)
  {
      NameValues.Add(new NameValue { Name = name, Value = obj, ValueType = type });
  }
}


[ProtoContract]
public class NameValue
{
  [ProtoMember(1)]
  public string Name { get; set; }
  [ProtoMember(2)]
  public object Value { get; set; }
  [ProtoMember(3)]
  public Type ValueType { get; set; }
}
```

serialization code

```csharp
var e1DataRows = new List<E1DataRow>();
/*
Code to add Data rows to e1DataRows
e1DataRow.AddNameValue(column.ColumnName, value, column.TypeOfColumn);
*/
using (var stream = File.OpenWrite(path))
{
  Serializer.Serialize(stream, e1DataRows);
}
```

```csharp
[ProtoMember(2, DynamicType = true)]
public object Value { get; set; }
```

*Above code throws following error (**DynamicType = true**)
ProtoMemberAttribute.DynamicType' is obsolete: 'Reference-tracking and dynamic-type are not currently implemented in this build; they may be reinstated later; this is partly due to doubts over whether the features are adviseable, and partly over confidence in testing all the scenarios (it takes time; that time hasn't get happened); feedback is invited'*

It would be great if you can help with how to serialize a List using Protobug-net. Thanks...

Comment: Looks like Protobuf-net handles generic types quite well. Try converting `public class NameValue` to `public class NameValue<T>` or use the existing 
`KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>` instead.

Comment: @schnitz77

Thanks for your comments. Problem with public class ```NameValue<T>``` is that then I can not have ```List<NameValue>``` with a different type (i guess).

```KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>``` is a good idea but would it cost me hashing operation, every time i add a new key.

Basically, I am trying to convert a dataset (SqlReader) into a simple POCO class for serialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look at https://github.com/dotarj/protobuf-net-data - this isn't affiliated with protobuf-net (different authors etc), but it *uses* protobuf-net to perform serialization of `DataTable` and data-readers, so it *might* do what you want ready-made.

---

As for implementing it yourself:

protobuf-net does not support `object` (or `dynamic`, which is just a fancy way of spelling `object`), fundamentally. There are ways of working around this, essentially similar to the `oneof` handling in protobuf - i.e. something like (in protobuf terms):

```proto
message Foo {
    oneof payload {
        string payload_string = 1;
        bool payload_bool = 2;
        int32 payload_int32 = 3;
        float payload_float = 4;
        // etc
    }
}
```

This is pretty easy to put together in protobuf-net thanks to "conditional serialization", which means you could do something like:

```cs
public object Value { get; set; }

[ProtoMember(1)]
public string ValueString
{
    get => (string)Value;
    set => Value = value;
}
public bool ShouldSerializeValueString()
    => Value is string;

[ProtoMember(2)]
public string ValueBoolean
{
    get => (bool)Value;
    set => Value = value;
}
public bool ShouldSerializeValueBoolean()
    => Value is string;

// etc
```

Comment: Thanks, Marc for your work on **protobuf-net**. I had hard error in using **protobuf-net-data** only to realize that it works with **2.3.2** version of your **protobuf-net** package. I understand the author of **protobuf-net-data** are different but do you have any idea if any work is going on to make it work with the latest version of your **protobuf-net** package.

Anyways once again thanks for the great work.

Answer (score 0):

If on c# >= 4 you might want to try the following:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class E1DataRow
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public List<NameValue<dynamic>> NameValues { get; set; }

    public E1DataRow()
    {
        NameValues = new List<NameValue<dynamic>>();
    }

    public void AddNameValue(string name, dynamic obj)
    {
        NameValues.Add(new NameValue<dynamic> { Name = name, Value = obj });
    }
}

public class NameValue<T>
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public T Value { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public Type ValueType { get { return Value.GetType(); } }
}
```

Not sure if Protobuf-net likes the `List<NameValue<dynamic>>`, can't test it as of now.

`ProtoMember(3)` at `ValueType` possibly is not necessary as of being readonly anyways.